# Embed m3u8 with flowplayer using JS

Tags: http-live-streaming, live-streaming, flowplayer, m3u8

[Here](http://demos.flowplayer.org/basics/live.html) is an example how to embed m3u8 with flowplayer.

```
<div data-live="true" data-ratio="0.5625" class="flowplayer play-button fixed-controls">
    <video>
        <source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="http://wms.shared.streamshow.it/telesanremo/telesanremo/playlist.m3u8" data-title="Live stream">
    </video>
</div>
```

Embedding RTMP using JS method:

```
flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
    clip: {
        url: 'streamname', 
        live: 'true', 
        provider: 'rtmp' 
    },
    plugins: {
        rtmp: {
            url: 'flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.13.swf', 
            netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://some_rtmp_link'
        } 
    } 
});
```

My question: is there a JavaScript or jQuery method to embed m3u8, like in RTMP example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

HTML:

```
<div id="player" class="fixed-controls"  style="width:600px; height:338px;"></div>
```

JS:

```
var api = flowplayer("#player", {
    live: true,
    splash: true,
    clip: {
        sources: [
            {
                type: "application/x-mpegurl",
                src: "http://srv6.zoeweb.tv:1935/z330-live/stream/playlist.m3u8"
            }
        ],
        title: "LiveStream"
    },
    embed: {
        skin: "http://releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.1/skin/bauhaus.css"
    }
});
```